# What to do when bounty asks a different question?

Tags: discussion

Specifically, I am referring to this:
[Using back to back zener diodes to clip voltage spikes in bipolar stepper motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38932/using-back-to-back-zener-diodes-to-clip-voltage-spikes-in-bipolar-stepper-motor)

It seems to me that the user posting the bounty is asking a question that is similar, but not the same as the original question, demanding a design for a slightly different problem.

It is not possible to comment, vote, or flag directly on the *bounty* without polluting the question.

Other than simply not engaging, what is the proper thing to do there?

Comment: related on meta SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280109/what-to-do-when-a-bounty-asks-a-different-question-than-the-original-question

Answer (score 4):

Offering a bounty on a question asked by another user is fine. However, answers will still have to address the original question *as asked by the OP* in order to be considered on-topic.

[Jodes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/4436/jodes) should ask the question posed in his bounty comment as a separate question. He's been around long enough that he should understand how the system works.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to answering the question as asked.  Personally, I don't even bother reading the bounty text as it's irrelevant.  I only noticed the additional question asked because you pointed it out here.

The proper way to ask for the additional information would have been to post a separate question referencing the first.  The asker of the second question could then offer a bounty after a while if no suitable answer emerged.

Basically, that bounty is a waste of 50 rep.  Oh well.  In a way it's justice for not bothering to understand the site before posting.